How to re query after update in tanstack/react-query
I am developing an app with react-native, supabase and @tanstack/react-query.
In the code below, when I open the menus.tsx screen, the useMenuList is executed immediately to fetch the data.
After executing useUpdateMenu and using router.back(), when reopening menus.tsx, the updated data is automatically re-fetched.

menus.tsx

const Menus = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: menus, error, isLoading } = useMenuList();



menus.ts

export const useMenuList = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["menus"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from("menus")
        .select("*")
        .order("menu_id", { ascending: true });
      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
      return data;
    },
  });
};

export const useUpdateMenu = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    async mutationFn({
      id,
      updatedFields,
    }: {
      id: number;
      updatedFields: UpdateTables<"menus">;
    }) {
      const { error, data: updatedMenu } = await supabase
        .from("menus")
        .update({
          field1: updatedFields.field1,
          field2: updatedFields.field2,
          field3: updatedFields.field3,
        })
        .eq("menu_id", id)
        .select()
        .single();

      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
      return updatedMenu;
    },
    async onSuccess(_, { id }) {
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["menus"] });
    },
  });
};

There is code in a similar format as the one above, with the difference being that instead of directly querying, it calls a function that performs the query.

users.tsx

const Users = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: users, error, isLoading, refetch } = useUsersWithMbr();


users.ts

export const useUsersWithMbr = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["useUsersWithMbr"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.rpc(
        "get_users_and_latest_membership"
      );

      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
      return data;
    },
  });
};

export const useUpdateUser = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    async mutationFn({
      id,
      updatedFields,
    }: {
      id: number;
      updatedFields: UpdateTables<"users">;
    }) {
      const { error, data: updatedUser } = await supabase
        .from("users")
        .update({
          token: updatedFields.token,
          user_type: updatedFields.user_type,
          branch_name: updatedFields.branch_name,
          user_name: updatedFields.user_name,
          contact: updatedFields.contact,
          description: updatedFields.description,
        })
        .eq("user_id", id)
        .select()
        .single();

      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
      return updatedUser;
    },
    async onSuccess(_, { id }) {
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["useUsersWithMbr"] });
    },
  });
};

There are two main differences between menus and users.
Firstly, when menus.tsx screen is opened, it directly performs a query, whereas users.tsx screen requires navigating away and returning for the data to be fetched.
Secondly, after updating and returning to their respective screens, menus automatically re-fetches the data, reflecting the changes made, while users still require navigating away and returning for the re-fetching to occur.
As I mentioned, the difference is only call function or not.
I've been struggling for a while.
Thank you for your help.
